# Filtering pattern in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was trying to find all the AAA nodes that have Status=Pending and don't have a RELATIONSHIP_1 relationship with BBB node.

I wrote 3 queries which should have returned the same count(according to my understanding):

```html
Match (a:AAA)-[tempRel]->(temp) where a.Status='Pending' AND TYPE(tempRel)<>'RELATIONSHIP_1' RETURN count(DISTINCT a)

Match (a:AAA)-[tempRel]->(temp:BBB) where a.Status='Pending' AND TYPE(tempRel)<>'RELATIONSHIP_1' RETURN count(DISTINCT a)


Match (a:AAA) where a.Status='Pending' AND NOT((a)-[:RELATIONSHIP_1]->(:BBB)) RETURN count(DISTINCT a)
```

But all the queries returned different results.

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 2):

1. The following matches any Pending `AAA` that has a non-`RELATIONSHIP_1` relationship to *any* node (with any label or no label). Note: a matching Pending `AAA` node could nevertheless also have a separate `RELATIONSHIP_1` relationship.

   ```
   MATCH (a:AAA)-[tempRel]->(temp)
   WHERE a.Status='Pending' AND TYPE(tempRel)<>'RELATIONSHIP_1'
   RETURN count(DISTINCT a)
   ```
2. The following matches any Pending `AAA` that has a non-`RELATIONSHIP_1` relationship to a `BBB` node. Note: a matching Pending `AAA` node could nevertheless also have a separate `RELATIONSHIP_1` relationship to a `BBB` node.

   ```
   MATCH (a:AAA)-[tempRel]->(temp:BBB)
   WHERE a.Status='Pending' AND TYPE(tempRel)<>'RELATIONSHIP_1'
   RETURN count(DISTINCT a)
   ```
3. The following matches any Pending `AAA` that does not have ANY `RELATIONSHIP_1` relationships to a `BBB` node. This includes Pending `AAA` nodes that do not have any relationships at all.

   ```
   MATCH (a:AAA)
   WHERE a.Status='Pending' AND NOT((a)-[:RELATIONSHIP_1]->(:BBB))
   RETURN count(DISTINCT a)
   ```